# How to plot 2D density clouds so that multiple clouds can be combined?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to make some similar plots like my first figure. I already used the code below to get the second figure. How can I obtain the same effect as the first figure?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read data
df=pd.read_excel('plot.xlsx')
df_data=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=df.columns)
df_data.dropna(how='any',subset=["F1","N1"],inplace=True)
m1=df_data.loc[:,['F1'][0]].values
m2=df_data.loc[:,['N1'][0]].values
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

#gaussian kernel density estimation
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z.reshape(X.shape), shading='gouraud', cmap=plt.cm.viridis)

plt.xlabel('F1')
plt.ylabel('N1')
plt.show()
```

Desired plot:

[image]

Current plot:

[image]

Comment: How does your data look like? How many rows do you have?  Maybe the first image is created using a third column to differentiate between 4 categories? How do you want to assign these categories in your case?

Comment: The same effect refers to a different color scheme, in my case, i only plotted one group data, and the other group data can not be added any more because of invisibility. Much thanks for your careful editorial work, Johan!

Comment: Does the new title fit your question better?  Can you comment on the number of data points?

Comment: Exactly，that's what i want to express. The number is about 600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seaborn's [`kdeplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot) with `fill=True` and setting a threshold (`thresh=` between 0 and 1) which cuts off the lowest densities. You may need to experiment to find a value that best fits your data. Note that nontransparent shapes are used, so the last one drawn will erase part of the previous ones.

If you have enough data, you can also create scatter plots with a very low alpha. Here also you'll need to experiment to find an alpha that works for your data.  If the number of points is very high, you'll also need to reduce the scatter dot size (and set the edgecolor to `'none'`). This approach handles overlap quite well, but needs sufficient data points.

Here is an example of both approaches:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

F1 = np.random.normal(85, 5, 1000)
N1 = np.random.normal(1700, 60, F1.size)
F2 = np.random.normal(55, 5, 1500)
N2 = np.random.normal(1800, 70, F2.size)
F3 = np.random.normal(45, 20, 2100)
N3 = np.random.normal(2200, 70, F3.size)
F4 = np.random.normal(50, 22, 2500)
N4 = np.random.normal(1400, 60, F4.size)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 5))
ax1.set_title('Seaborn kdeplot')
sns.kdeplot(x=F1, y=N1, cmap='Blues', fill=True, thresh=0.02, ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(x=F2, y=N2, cmap='Reds', fill=True, thresh=0.02, ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(x=F3, y=N3, cmap='Greens', fill=True, thresh=0.02, ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(x=F4, y=N4, cmap='Purples', fill=True, thresh=0.02, ax=ax1)

ax2.set_title('Scatter plot with high transparency')
ax2.scatter(F1, N1, color='blue', alpha=0.02)
ax2.scatter(F2, N2, color='red', alpha=0.02)
ax2.scatter(F3, N3, color='green', alpha=0.02)
ax2.scatter(F4, N4, color='purple', alpha=0.02)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]